# Assert a set of arguments are strings without is_string()?

Tags: php

```
public static function GetDirectLoginUser($username, $password)
{
    if (!is_string($username))
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Usernames must be strings.');
    }
    if (!is_string($password))
    {
        throw new InvalidArgumentException('Passwords must be strings.');
    }
```

This is fine for two arguments... but for e.g. 7 arguments it becomes ridiculous. Is there a better way of handling that?

Comment: @JaredFarrish: Because I don't want to have 7 different if statements at the beginning of a method to test for and deal with.

Comment: Then deal with the method's arguments. I don't know why in practice this really makes any difference.

Comment: If that's really a problem you expect *at runtime / in production*, you have bigger problems with the application architecture. That's the most pointless exception class in existence. Really. But use `assert(array_sum(array_map("is_string", func_get_args()))==2);` or something to shorten.

Comment: @mario: Of course it's not something you should see in production. But it's extremely common in libraries. You don't want client code to crash strangely because (s)he specified an `int` instead of a string.

Comment: I'm just saying that I would consider that a *development* problem. Entirely a development problem. And it seems a waste of memory to prepare well-written error messages for such edge cases. An assert() at most should suffice, even for a library. Invalid parameter types are *always* caught at development time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a better way of handling that?

Don't check. Caller beware.

Answer (score 1):

I'd do something like this, if possible for your case:

```
public static function someMethod($username, $password, $something, $else)
{
    foreach( array( 'username', 'password', 'something', 'else' ) as $mustBeString )
    {
        // using variable variable here
        // who would have thought I'd ever propose that :)
        if( !is_string( $$mustBeString ) )
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException( ucfirst( $mustBeString ) . 's must be strings.');
        }
    }

    // etc..
```

Answer (score 0):

Not really. If they were objects or arrays yes (through the argument signature), but not strings.

Answer (score 0):

You could always do this:

```
public static function GetDirectLoginUser($username, $password)
{
    foreach (array("username" => $username, "password" => $password) as $name => $arg)
    {
        if (!is_string($arg))
        {
            throw new InvalidArgumentException("The $name must be a string.");
        }
    }
```

But really, usually it would be better to simply [cast the arguments into the type you need](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php):

```
public static function GetDirectLoginUser($username, $password)
{
    $username = (string) $username;
    $password = (string) $password;
```

Or, easier yet, just use the arguments as if they were strings, and PHP will (usually) convert them to strings automatically.  Most of the time, you really shouldn't worry about whether a PHP variable is, say, a number or a string — if you use it as a number, PHP will treat it as a number; if you use it as a string, PHP will treat it as a string.